# Is it legal to convert a not-freely-distributable font to "path" and distribute it?

Tags: fonts, legal, path

Suppose, I am creating a logo in a vector graphics editor (for example [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)) and I use there the font which cannot be freely distributed (for example [Myriad Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myriad_%28typeface%29) which can be obtained by downloading Adobe Reader).

Then I convert the text, which uses the not-freely-distributable font, to "path" (for example, Inkscape can do it), so all the information about the used font will be lost.

Is it legal to distribute such a logo (the font is no longer embedded in the logo, it was converted to path)?

Comment: Really grey area! In the UK, **using** a font is fine, but creating a derivative work is not (without the appropriate licence). You are using the font, and then creating a derivative work of it. Consult an IP lawyer!

Comment: @AndrewLeach is it actually a gray area? In the US, it's a tool of the trade. It's like licensing music. As long as you aren't breaking the license, you're good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legality is governed by the license. As far as Adobe products are concerend it appears that YES, you may use a typeface within a logo *as long as you do not distribute the font file*.

The arbiter of this is the **license** and **licenses vary**.

An answer from an apparent Adobe employee ( http://forums.adobe.com/message/5106212 )

> You certainly may use any of the fonts bundled with Adobe applications
>   for a logo or similar static content. You may also embed the font in
>   the resultant PDF file or EPS file that you create for the logo for
>   placement in other content. What you cannot do is give out the font
>   file itself to others. By having the font embedded in the PDF or EPS
>   (PDF is the preferred format, by the way), you avoid any such problems
>   or limitations. Note that this is true for Adobe fonts, but not
>   necessarily fonts from other vendors.

My personal opinion is that this is not "derivative" in the normal sense because the sole function of a typeface file is to create works derived from it.

Comment: I think it's fair to call it derivative, but it's LICENSED derivative work. ;)