# How to exchange individual glyphs between fonts

Tags: fonts

I am using the font Trajan Pro in a logo that also includes an ampersand (&). I would like to use the same font in paragraphs of text documents; unfortunately Trajan Pro does not feature lower-case glyphs. The La Gioconda font seems to solve this problem, because it is an extension of Trajan that includes lower-case glyphs. However, the ampersand symbol is not the same.

Is it possible to replace the ampersand in the La Gioconda font with the Trajan Pro ampersand, yielding a combined font? If so, what is the best way to do this?

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could edit the font to do that. Sounds like unnecessary complication. Instead, can't you just change the font when you type the ampersand character?

Comment: The problem is that the "combined font" is to be used by a lot of people who are not designers and who will not consciously pay attention to this, but instead will just use a template they are given as it is. Can you recommend any good free tool that runs on Mac OS and can do this?

Comment: Given the above comment, it sounds like you're better off creating your own hybrid font for the non-designers to use.  I don't create fonts myself, but I think [Font Forge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) is a pretty popular program.

Comment: [check this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19734/is-there-any-open-source-alternative-to-fontlab-out-there/19735#19735) but also don't forget to check [this one for possible legal implications](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19256/is-it-legal-to-convert-a-not-freely-distributable-font-to-path-and-distribute)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John Manly and Luciano. Not sure how else to make this work for a non-designer, other than finding a new font for them to use across the board instead of forcing two to work together.

If you were trying to accomplish this in an Adobe program and not worrying about non-designers... I know that in InDesign, you are able to use Find/Replace to replace font formatting. You could Find all & in the La Giocondo font, and replace with & in the Trajan font. You could probably do the same in Illustrator, and possibly Photoshop but not sure.